# How to read xml in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Could anyone tell me how I could select values from the following xml:
I would like to get rows as follows:
Col1: key, Col2: key, Col3: value

```
1 1 value
1 2 value2
1 3 value3

2 4 value4
2 5 value5
2 6 value6
```

Here is the xml:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <key>1</key>
    <value>
      <params>
        <item>
          <key>1</key>
          <value>value</value>      
        </item>
        <item>
          <key>2</key>
          <value>value2</value>     
        </item>     
        <item>
          <key>3</key>
          <value>value3</value>     
        </item>     
      </params>
    </value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>2</key>
    <value>
      <params>
        <item>
          <key>4</key>
          <value>value4</value>     
        </item>
        <item>
          <key>5</key>
          <value>value5</value>     
        </item>     
        <item>
          <key>6</key>
          <value>value6</value>     
        </item>     
      </params>
    </value>
  </item>  
</root>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have this XML in a T-SQL variable - then you could use this snippet of code:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '...(your XML here).....'

SELECT
    Key1 = Item.value('(key)[1]', 'int'),
    Key2 = Item2.value('(key)[1]', 'int'),
    ItemValue = Item2.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/root/item') AS T(Item)
CROSS APPLY
    item.nodes('value/params/item') AS T2(Item2)
```

This gives me an output of:

```
Key1  Key2  ItemValue
 1     1     value
 1     2     value2
 1     3     value3
 2     4     value4
 2     5     value5
 2     6     value6
```

The approach is the following:

- grab the list of `<item>` nodes under `<root>` as your first "list of XML nodes" with the first `.nodes()` XQuery method, and extract the value of the `<key>` XML element in that XML fragment into `Key1`
- grab the "nested" list of XML nodes inside that XML fragment, using the `value/params/item` XPath, to get the child rows - and extract the values from `<key>` and `<value>` from those nested child XML fragments into `Key2` and `ItemValue`

Comment: Cool That's what I've been looking for. I thought that somehow I will have to enumerate twice from the specific leaf but hasn't known I can use 'Item' from the first nodes. Thanks again!