# how can i read multiple xml values from URL through t-sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[How to read xml in t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999813/how-to-read-xml-in-t-sql)

I have followed the above solution, but still i could not able to achieve it..

Here is my XML

```
 <result>
  <count>2</count>
  <rows>
<row>
  <f>
    <n>id</n>
    <v>8557526</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>vdb_id</n>
    <v>16239</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>created</n>
    <v>2014-12-10T08:50:18</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>task_id</n>
    <v>5755155</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>process_id</n>
    <v />
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>update_comments</n>
    <v />
  </f>
</row>
<row>
  <f>
    <n>id</n>
    <v>8567425</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>vdb_id</n>
    <v>16239</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>created</n>
    <v>2014-12-11T00:23:59</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>task_id</n>
    <v>5755155</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>process_id</n>
    <v />
  </f>        
  <f>
    <n>update_comments</n>
    <v />
  </f>
</row>
```

query :

```
  USE tempdb
GO

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml
  CREATE TABLE #xml ( yourXML XML )
   GO

  DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 

  DECLARE @QS varchar(50)

  SELECT @QS = '&date='+convert(varchar(25),getdate(),126)
  SELECT @URL = 'https://app.is.com/psa/api.do?function=query&table=db_time_entry&     project_id=227666&token=c9adf' + @QS


   DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
   DECLARE @XML xml
   DECLARE @Obj int 
   DECLARE @Result int 
   DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
   DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)


   EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Obj OUT 

   EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
   EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 

    INSERT #xml ( yourXML )
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 

     --SELECT  yourXML.value('//result[1]//count[1]//rows[1]//row[1]//f[1]//n[1]//v[1]  /id','VARCHAR(MAX)') from #xml

    DECLARE @xml_value xml

     select * from #xml
     select @xml_value = yourXML  from #xml
```

I tried this one

```
 SELECT
  Key1 = Item.value('(n)[1]', 'int'),
  Key2 = Item2.value('(n)[1]', 'int'),
   ItemValue = Item2.value('(v)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
 FROM 
   @xml_value.nodes('/result/rows') AS T(Item)
 CROSS APPLY
item.nodes('row/f') AS T2(Item2)
```

i got the out put like this

```
    Key2    ItemValue
     id      8557526
     vdb_id   16239
     created    2014-12-10T08:50:18
     task_id    5755155
    process_id  
    update_comments 
      id    8567425
       vdb_id   16239
      created   2014-12-11T00:23:59
      task_id   5755155
     process_id 
       update_comments
```

I need Output Like

```
ID    vdb_id   created   task_id   process_id    update_comments

 8557526   16239  2014-12-10  5755155  null   null
```

please anyone tell me how I could select values from the XML and get the desired output
Thanks in advance

Regards

T.Navin

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `SQL Server`, Use `PIVOT` to get the desired result .

```
DECLARE @xmlData AS XML


  SET @xmlData = CAST('<result>
  <count>2</count>
  <rows>
<row>
  <f>
    <n>id</n>
    <v>8557526</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>vdb_id</n>
    <v>16239</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>created</n>
    <v>2014-12-10T08:50:18</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>task_id</n>
    <v>5755155</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>process_id</n>
    <v />
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>update_comments</n>
    <v />
  </f>
</row>
<row>
  <f>
    <n>id</n>
    <v>8567425</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>vdb_id</n>
    <v>16239</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>created</n>
    <v>2014-12-11T00:23:59</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>task_id</n>
    <v>5755155</v>
  </f>
  <f>
    <n>process_id</n>
    <v />
  </f>        
  <f>
    <n>update_comments</n>
    <v />
  </f>
</row>
</rows>
</result>' AS XML)

SELECT Piv.Id, piv.[vdb_id], piv.[created], piv.[task_id], piv.[update_comments] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Result1.value('v[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS A, 
           Result1.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS B,
         DENSE_RANK() over(order by Result) AS Num
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('//result/rows/row') xmlData(Result) 
    CROSS APPLY xmlData.Result.nodes('./f') xmlData1(Result1)
) AS A    
Pivot (Min(A) FOR B IN ([id],
                        [vdb_id],
                        [created],
                        [task_id],
                        [update_comments])
       ) piv
```

Comment: if i dont want to store the process_id column in my table , what should i do?

Comment: @navbingo: Remove the [process_id] in PIVOT column list. I updated the result, verify it.

Comment: ok thanks... but i am facing another problem.. it is displaying only one row ;(

Comment: i have edited my question.. i have added an image.. i am running two queries.. the second one is the pivot one (ur's).. the first query showing all the 8 records (total 32 xml columns * 8 =256).. where as the pivot one shows only one record..

Comment: @navbingo: I have updated the result. verify it and let me know the status.

Comment: is it possible to give alias name , for example [id] as PRJ_ID when i tried like this it showed me error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
and is it possible to get date time in our desired format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: i have created a temp table and inserted the pivot output , so there i gave the required column names.. from there i convert the date also ;) thanks a lot

Comment: I have attached the screen shot for your reference.. please help.. is it possible to chat from here

Comment: the data is mismatching.. the XML data is correct.. after that , it is getting mismatched .. in orderby part only it is getting changed.. just few mins before only i noticed ..

Comment: to be frank.. i am just waiting for your  positive reply.. hope u understand.. thanks once again

Comment: @navbingo: I fixed the issue and updated the result query in answer. Verify it and let me know the status.