# How to convert rows into columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

i have generated a temp table from xml and it has the following structure

```
   column1    column2
     id         1234
     code      ukjk
     .
     .
      there will be another 60 rows again
     id         4586
     code       ouiu 
     .
     . 
       there will be another 60 rows again
     id          78545
     code         khdsjf

     like this there will be 15 id's in the table
```

Now i want to convert the rows into column like

i don't want all the 60 i need just 5 of them

```
      id   code   vdb_id    guid ....
      1234
      4586
      78545
```

and also i have attached the XML file image..

i have used pivot function

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml_final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml_final
   CREATE TABLE #xml_final (rownum int, Project_id int, Project_Name varchar(60),     Project_manager_id int, Updated_date varchar(60) )

    insert into  #xml_final
    SELECT * FROM

  (

      SELECT xmlData.Result.value('v[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS A,
       xmlData.Result.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS B,
     ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY xmlData.Result.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(200)')
          order by xmlData.Result.value('v[1]','VARCHAR(200)')) AS Num
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('//result/rows/row/f') xmlData(Result)

  ) AS A
   Pivot (Min(A) FOR B IN ([id] ,
                    [summary],
                    [manager_id],
                    [ts]
                    )
   ) piv
```

But it is not working properly.. i am getting mismatch error

for example

```
     id 1234  i am getting code as ouiu
```

## output2 Table will have 3 columns

```
    row_num    key2    item_value
        1    id        1234
        5   proj_id     7655
        9   task_name    kfhkjfdhg
       21   id         5455
       25   proj_id     6789797
       29   task_name   dsyhuiyfhdi
```

and key2 will contain only these 3 column names

output i want to have is,

```
    id     proj_id    task_name

  1234     7655        kfhkjfdhg
  5455   6789797    dsyhuiyfhdi



     DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + QUOTENAME(key2) 
                from #output_2
                group by key2, row_num
                order by row_num
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

   set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select item_value, key2
            from #output_2
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(item_value)
            for key2 in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

  print @query
  exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Updated Query

```
     DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(max)='',
    @sql     NVARCHAR(max)

     SELECT @columns += COL
      FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT '[' + Isnull(key2, '') + '],' col
    FROM   #output_2
    WHERE  item_value IS NOT NULL) a   

     SELECT @columns = LEFT(@columns, Len(@columns) - 1)


      SET @sql ='SELECT rownum,' + @columns + '
      FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY item_value) rownum,
               *
        FROM   #output_2)a
       PIVOT(Max(item_value)
            FOR key2 IN(' + @columns + ')) piv '

            Print @sql

       EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

**Updated Query 2:**

```
      IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#output_3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #output_3
      CREATE TABLE #output_3 (   row_id int, row_num int , task_id int, project_id int, task_name   varchar(200) )

     insert into #output_3
     SELECT Row_number() over (ORDER BY (select null)) row_id ,  rownum,(id),(project_id),(summary)
       FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY (select null))     rownum,
               *
        FROM   #output_2)a
       PIVOT(Max(item_value)
            FOR key2 IN([id],[project_id],[summary])) piv


      select row_id, task_id, task_name, project_id  from   #output_3
```

output:

[image]

**INSERT QUERY**

```
      IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#output') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #output
   CREATE TABLE #output ( id int ,key2 varchar(50), item_value varchar(200) )

   insert into #output 
      select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as SNumber, 
     key2 = Item2.value('(n)[1]','varchar(50)'),
     ItemValue = Item2.value('(v)[1]','varchar(50)')
      from
       @xmlData.nodes('/result/rows') as T(Item)
     cross apply
     item.nodes('row/f') as T2(Item2)
```

How to solve this issue..

[how can i read multiple xml values from URL through t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438260/how-can-i-read-multiple-xml-values-from-url-through-t-sql)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your expected output is not clear!

Comment: @NoDisplayName : i have added an image , how the expected output should look like

Comment: @NoDisplayName : i have added a link , from there only i have framed the tsql query for xml input..

Comment: While saving into temp table initially can't we save details as required.. I mean instead of storing into columns can you store directly into the required schema

Comment: @irvgk yes we can do .. but i am new to this.. could you please help me out , how to proceed further..

Answer (score 2):

Try this. change your `Pivot Query` like this

```
create table #output(key2 varchar(50),item_value varchar(50))

insert #output
values 
('id','1234'),('code','ukjk'),('GUID','DFG'),
('SRC',null),('TS',null),('workspcd','3245'),
('id','4586'),('code','ouiu'),('GUID','ff'),
('SRC',null),('TS',null),('workspcd','2233'),
('id','78545'),('code','khdsdf'),('GUID','dffff'),
('SRC',null),('TS',null),('workspcd','3234')

SELECT rownum,[id],[code],[GUID],[workspcd]
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY item_value) rownum,
               *
        FROM   #output)a
       PIVOT(Max(item_value)
            FOR key2 IN([id],[code],[GUID],[SRC],[TS],[workspcd])) piv
```

**UPDATE :** To work Dynamically

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @columns += COL
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT '[' + Isnull(key2, '') + '],' col
        FROM   #output
        WHERE  item_value IS NOT NULL) a

SELECT @columns = LEFT(@columns, Len(@columns) - 1)

SET @sql ='SELECT rownum,' + @columns + '
    FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY item_value) rownum,
                   *
            FROM   #output)a
           PIVOT(Max(item_value)
                FOR key2 IN(' + @columns + ')) piv '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
rownum  id      code    GUID    workspcd
------  ----    ------  -----   --------
1       1234    khdsdf  dffff   2233
2       4586    ouiu    DFG     3234
3       78545   ukjk    ff      3245
```

**Update** to remove NULL values

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) row_id,
       rownum,
       Max(id)                     id,
       Max(project_id)             project_id,
       Max(summary)                summary
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   PARTITION BY key2
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rownum,
               *
        FROM   #output_2)a
       PIVOT(Max(item_value)
            FOR key2 IN([id],
                        [project_id],
                        [summary])) piv
GROUP  BY rownum
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66913/discussion-on-answer-by-nodisplayname-how-to-convert-rows-into-columns-in-sql-se).